# Pandas: Series of timestamps comparison produces a typeerror

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

The following code gives me a TypeError:

```
slicer = df.picked_up.notnull() & df.pickup_by.notnull()
df[slicer].picked_up < df[slicer].pickup_by
```

I get `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to long` on the last line.

But when I do

```
slicer = df.picked_up.notnull() & df.pickup_by.notnull()
df[slicer].apply(lambda x: x["picked_up"] < x["pickup_by"], axis=1)
```

I don't get any errors. The problem is that `apply()` takes a very long time and I'm trying to cut it out where I can. I'm trying to find out which entries are problematic, but I can't identify any entries that are type "long":

```
print df.picked_up.map(type).unique(), df.pickup_by.map(type).unique()

> [<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'> <class 'pandas.tslib.NaTType'>] [<type 'NoneType'> <type 'datetime.datetime'>]
```

And

```
print df[slicer].picked_up.map(type).unique(), df[slicer].pickup_by.map(type).unique()

> [<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>] [<type 'datetime.datetime'>]
```

**How can I identify where these problematic `long` elements are if the `type` function says there aren't any?**

Using pandas version 0.15.2

Note: Converting with `pd.to_timestamp()` beforehand doesn't work either.